# Redirect to Page URL for non-members

Tags: wp-redirect

My membership plug in won't let me re-direct custom post type archive / taxonomy URLs to a non-member page if the user requesting access is not logged in or not a member. So, I am trying a hack to check if user is Level A, B, C etc and if not the template page redirects to a no access page.

I'm using the code below to check for access levels. What would be the best way to insert a  page redirect?

```
<?php 
     if(mgm_user_is(array('level1','level2' ))) {

echo 'REDIRECT TO NON-MEMBER PAGE';

} else {
echo 'GIVES ACCESS TO PAGE SEARCHED FOR';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use wp_redirect for that. Here is a simple code, it redirects non-users to website homepage. You can redirect them to a error page or on signup page.

```
<?php
  if( mgm_user_is( array('level1', 'level2' ) ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  } else {
    // show content
  }
?>
```